What site statistics might indicate that our site is ready to graduate from beta?
Nick raised the question of whether some of our improving  site statistics suggested we were ready for launch. I figured this might be an interesting meta discussion.

Nick: We're now in the "okay" range with 5.5 questions per day! Time to start pushing for a launch maybe? It has already been 750 days
  as of today.
Jeromy: Hi Nick, it's great that we've got questions per day in the okay range. My sense from these site stats
  stackexchange.com/sites#traffic across the network is that we're
  moving in the right direction, but that we're still a while off
  launch. Just looking, other sites that are launched typically have
  10,000+ visits/day. 
Nick: Wow! That is quite a while off. However, if that's your estimate for currently launched sites, might having been launched
  already be a causal factor in the extra traffic? That is, I assume SE
  isn't looking for beta sites to reach the same level of traffic as
  fully-launched sites before actually launching them. Area51's criteria
  for "excellent" status in this particular dimension certainly seem to
  suggest otherwise...but I also suspect that there's more involved in
  the decision "behind the scenes" than these five statistics, and I'm a
  little pessimistic of getting any insight by asking.

Question

How will we know that we are ready to go out of beta?
What site statistics might suggest that we are ready?


Thanks for promoting and answering my thoughts! With your answer alone, this is already a very useful question! FWIW, the reason I'm pessimistic about getting insight by asking on Area51 (not here from all you fine fellows!): I earned the tumbleweed badge for this question of mine on Area51, which I admit was a little intimidating in length and complexity...(most of which could be ignored if one were simply to assume the bolded questions up top deserve attention in any case!)

This discussion might be helpful.

Official words on graduation:
This post on the stack exchange blog on when sites will graduate from beta is one source of information. It states:

So from this point forward, the graduation date of a site will depend
  heavily on having enough users with sufficient reputation to properly
  lead and govern the site.

Also, the point is made that:

There’s no harm in staying in public beta far beyond the initial 90 days

Inferring from other sites:
The official page of StackExchange site statistics gives a good sense of how we stack up relative to other sites including both other beta sites and graduated sites. Here's a screen shot of a rough cross-over point. 

Of course, there are several beta sites above these, and a few graduated sites below this. Also, visits per day is not everything. Of the graduated sites that are below, they often graduated early and feature high quality content and often many questions. If I were to guess, I think we should be aiming for:

10,000+ questions
At least 80% answered, but higher would be better
10,000+ visits per day
15 questions per day
And a general good standard of content, moderation, and active users

But to reiterate, I don't think it matters too much whether we're in beta or not.
Does graduating increase traffic? I'm not really sure. But I don't think it would make much difference. There are plenty of beta sites with huge traffic, and non-beta sites with low traffic. The difference in site design is just a bit of polish and the removal of the word "beta". The actual content doesn't really change.

SE certainly seems to be in no hurry to graduate Personal Finance & Money, given statistics as enviable as those...One counterargument about graduation's potential effect on traffic though: don't underestimate the effects of polish and the word "beta". My tied-for-second-most-upvoted answer so far speaks to the power of polish a little bit, albeit in a rather incomplete and indirect way (pardon the shameless plug BTW). Beta status is also an implicit threat of sorts that the site may not continue to grow past some point in the future...

...if, when SE does make up its mind, it doesn't decide in our favor. This is a substantial concern for me as a psychologist, because I'd probably rather spend my time writing journal articles and conducting research if my work here isn't going to continue to grow in relevance without continuing effort on my part, or if my ability to provide that continuing effort here may come to an end. I don't know if others feel the same, and I'd hate to disincentivize others by spreading my own concerns unnecessarily, but I'm sure that the experts this site needs would appreciate more long-term assurance.

Regarding "personal finance" I've heard several questions raised about the degree to which the answers reflect deep expertise; contrast that with a graduated site like "theoretical computer science" where I've heard you have some serious academics posting questions and answers.

Ah yes, the inscrutable, amorphous criterion of answer quality...Small wonder we don't have site statistics automatically calculated, displayed, and judged for that! I'm afraid a behind-the-scenes criterion like that could be a particular threat here, because even professional cognitive scientists vary widely in their ability to critique others work and the thresholds they set for "good enough".

The content is creative commons CC-BY licenced and backed up in public places. So the content wont be lost. I see no signs that the site will be closed. We have positive trajectory; it just takes time. If we got out of beta in two years, I'd be happy. However, I wouldn't stress too much about the beta thing. But at the same time I wouldn't spend so much time here that you're not pumping out papers. Which reminds me, I better get back to it :-)

Ha! Good for you; my former advisor certainly agrees. I'm not worried (much less stressed :) about losing the content; just that if it ever gets archived, its content won't continue to aggregate and attract cumulative attention and structure. That active, organically evolving quality is what makes SE worth diverting my attention from the usual professional forums (i.e., journals/books/etc.), so for me personally, I'm afraid the likelihood of closure makes much of the difference in the site's value. I agree we're moving up for now though, so for me, it's a matter of planning, not pessimism. :)

Here are some insights I've picked up today:

The fabled "critical mass" seems to be an inflection point in rate of change in site traffic

Quite usefully visible on quαntcast! Could give us some good feedback for promotional efforts.
Hence we have badges for sharing questions to social media (e.g., our Facebook page ;).
A "critical mass" traffic trend seems to have precipitated Home Improvement's graduation.
Personal Finance & Money is getting theirs too! About time eh? Three cheers for our peers!

# of users with >2K and >3K rep matters for handling edits and close votes after launch.


We're currently sitting at 11 and 7 respectively...Guess I'm poised to make it 12 & 7 soon :)
We should consider their personal activity too. Ours have all visited in the past few weeks!
Making more users like these is one of the reasons Jeff Atwood wants us to rock the vote!

Quality matters (but good luck measuring it), so don't just throw those votes around randomly either.


@MadScientist says quality is very important, and likely to encourage launch / prevent closure.
Quality probably affects user retention, which probably affects traffic accumulation over time.
Unanswered questions that aren't worth answering might deserve site-wide cleanup efforts.

The statistics Area 51 displays are a bit like a pulse reading...an index of the site's health right now

At least in the case of questions per day: that's a 2-week moving average.
Not sure about others; I've seen visits per day move around a little, but not the others.
% answered can matter, at least as a "saving grace"...more reason to clean up lame questions.


References

Blogs by SE Director of Community Development Robert Cartaino:


When Will My Site Graduate?
Does this site have a chance of succeeding?

These questions Robert responded to:


How do I know if a beta Stack Exchange site is growing well? (+1 for Mad Scientist's answer!)
What exactly does it take to get a site out of public beta? [closed]
What are the criteria for getting Money.SE out of “perpetual beta?”
What happens now?

A question Jeff Atwood responded to:


When is Personal Finance and Money going to get out of beta?

A very useful post by @Shog9 on Personal Finance and Money's meta:


The future of Personal Finance and Money


